# How can edit a menu on profile installing?

Tags: 7, distributions

I want to edit Management Menu in drupal7 when my profile is installing and active expanded check mark in Administration item.
i user this method:

```
db_update('menu_links')
->fields(array('expanded' => 1))
->condition('menu_name', 'management')
->condition('link_title', 'Administration')
->execute();
```

but do not see any action!!! not work! plz help.

Comment: Have you checked to see if that table contains the expected records before you run the update?

Comment: Yes, that is checked.

Comment: @pdan I have the same issue.. Can you please share if you found any solution..